# Java BufferedImage.createGraphics thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedimage

I am running a web server that retrieves images and does some manipulation on them.  Everything works fine in unit tests, but today the web server became unresponsive, and upon doing a thread dump I see a lot of blocked threads with the following stack trace:

```
sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(java.awt.image.BufferedImage) @bci=19, li

ne=181 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(java.awt.image.BufferedImage) @bci=5, line=89 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics() @bci=6, line=1154 (Compiled frame)
 - (my package).getScaledInstance(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int, java.lang.Object, boolean) @bci=113, line=120 (Compiled frame)
```

The line of (my) code that it gets stuck on is:

```
        BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
        Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
```

Is createGraphics thread-safe?  I cannot find any documentation in the official javadocs stating that it isn't, but it sure looks that way(and considering that it's based on AWT, it wouldn't surprise if it wasn't).  Is there anything else that could cause the thread to block like this?

EDIT: should add that I am running on an Amazon EC2 Linux ami(the default one), running the latest version of java,

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Creating an SSCCE for something as ephemeral as thread safety, esp. for thread safety re. a single 3rd party call is far from "simple".

Comment: That's why they pay us the big bucks.  BTW - I never mentioned 'simple'.  Why did you bring it up?

Comment: SSCE used to contain the word "simple", but at any rate, your comment is not at all constructive.  A question on whether or not a method is thread safe does not require an example.  Either the method is thread-safe or it is not.  Creating an SSCCE is almost impossible as something that may in fact lock up on my machine may not on yours, as it would be impossible for me to inject delays etc. into 3rd party code that can reliably trigger deadlock.

Comment: *"(S)SSCE used to contain the word "simple""*  As the author of the SSCCE document, I can tell you with all confidence that it *never* contained the word simple, ***ever***.  Though that was a common misconception.  *"Creating an SSCCE is almost impossible"*  Really?  It seems fairly trivial to me to create a method that calls it repeatedly, at random time intervals, and see if anything screws up over time (might take a few minutes).  But then it is your problem, so I'll let you figure that out ..or not.

Comment: Can you get access to the stack trace from `kill -QUIT <javaPid>`?  If so, I think it would be useful to post that here if it's not too huge.

Comment: By convention all methods in java are thread-safe unless noted otherwise. Graphics might use surface caching. Please use jstack to capture the entire stack of the process to check if there is any contention.